# TranslatorRegistry Cake 3

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

Follow document Cake\I18n\TranslatorRegistry at method get()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5dLH.png)

The return value is object (Aura\Intl\TranslatorInterface)

In my local it working as well, but in staging some time it working well and some time it got error:

> Call to undefined method Cake\Routing\RouteCollection::GetPackage()
> (/var/www/vhosts/project/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/TranslatorRegistry.php:148)

I don’t understand what is the cause to problem.

Hope someone can help me this. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your cache is messed up. `TranslatorRegistry::get()` uses the cache key `translations.$name.$locale` to look up / cache the translator, and for whatever reason it finds a cached route collection object for that key. Not much anyone here could do, you'll have to debug further how your application is caching data, and what exactly lands in the cache. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in  `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ndm ,my current CakePHP version is 3.8.13.
I don't know why it can be like that, if TranslatorRegistry::get() wrong cache, so why refresh again it working normal like nothing happen.
I'm trying to debug the caching data.